# Javascript - On click handler ignored/skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, eventhandler

I have the below piece of code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        var rebuild = getParameterByName("rebuild");

        var createdStructures = $('#AtoZContentDiv').children().length;


        if ((rebuild !== undefined && rebuild !== null && rebuild.indexOf("true") === 0) || (createdStructures === 0))
        {
            // clean up pre-existing data
            cleanUp();


            // create container structure
            createFormLinkContainers();

            // Call SP web services to retrieve the information and create the A to Z
            retrieveListData();

            completeInitialization();
        }
        else
        {
            aggregateAll = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregateAll').val());
            aggregatePersonal = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregatePersonal').val());
            aggregateBusiness = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregateBusiness').val());
            ministryAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnMinistryAggregate').val());
            caAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnCAAggregate').val());
            sTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnSTaxAggregate').val());
            bTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnBTaxAggregate').val());
            leTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnLETaxAggregate').val());

            var type = getParameterByName("filter");

        $( "#tab-all" ).click(function()
        {
                loadit('all');
        });         


        $( "#tab-business" ).click(function()
        {
            loadit('business');
        });

        $( "#tab-personal" ).click(function()
        {

        });


        $(document).on('click','#tab-personal',function(e){
         loadit('personal');    
        });


                buildFilterMenu();
                loadit('all');
        }
    });
```

I have tried using both:

```
$(document).on('click','#tab-personal',function(e){
 loadit('personal');    
});
```

and

```
$( "#tab-personal" ).click(function()
{

});
```

and when I place a breakpoint inside any of them, none are hit.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" style="display: inline-block;">
    <ul><li><a class="selected" id="tab-all" href="#" type="all"><b>All Forms</b></a></li>
    <li><a id="tab-business" href="#" type="business"><b>Business</b> </a></li>
    <li><a id="tab-personal" href="#" type="personal"><b>Personal</b> </a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Full Code: http://pastebin.com/vzLPX3cU

Why is this happening?

Comment: did you try to execute adding listener in console? Try this:  $( "#tab-personal" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( "click!" );
});

Comment: I put a breakpoint in Chrome's developer tools debugger. I had tried putting a console.log('<<<<personal') but the code was not hit.

Comment: example with you DOM works https://jsfiddle.net/k06w4mos/. Maybe you have some errors and your code doesn't execute completely?

Comment: @Sabik This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/vzLPX3cU . I did not post the full code as I assumed the document.ready part would be enough since JS is interpreted from within that function. I could not find any errors in the code (even used JS Syntax validators) with no errors.

Comment: What about your if statement? Maybe listeners didn't add to element?

Comment: I think, the problem is, you have added the event inside else condition. Because of which it is not hitting. try using out side of else condition.

Comment: My answer has been edited. Please check with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var rebuild = getParameterByName("rebuild");
    var createdStructures = $('#AtoZContentDiv').children().length;
    if ((rebuild !== undefined && rebuild !== null && rebuild.indexOf("true") === 0) || (createdStructures === 0)){
        // clean up pre-existing data
        cleanUp();

        // create container structure
        createFormLinkContainers();

        // Call SP web services to retrieve the information and create the A to Z
        retrieveListData();
        completeInitialization();
    }else{
        aggregateAll = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregateAll').val());
        aggregatePersonal = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregatePersonal').val());
        aggregateBusiness = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnAggregateBusiness').val());
        ministryAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnMinistryAggregate').val());
        caAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnCAAggregate').val());
        sTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnSTaxAggregate').val());
        bTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnBTaxAggregate').val());
        leTaxAggregate = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hdnLETaxAggregate').val());

        var type = getParameterByName("filter");
            buildFilterMenu();
            loadit('all');
    }
    $( "#tab-all" ).click(function(){
            loadit('all');
    });         

    $( "#tab-business" ).click(function(){
        loadit('business');
    });

    $(document).on('click','#tab-personal',function(e){
        loadit('personal');    
    });
});
```

Comment: A separate $(document).ready() you mean? Because the code is already like that.

Comment: yes, the click event should be inside `$(document).ready()` function. And make sure you have included Jquery library.

Comment: I did not understand the changes you made to the code. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I have removed all you click event out of the `each` condition. and placed it out side the each condition.

Comment: It still does not work. Seems the code is correct but the functionality/logic maybe isn't.

Comment: Is you HTML is rendering at run time? If it is then `$(document).on('click','#tab-personal',function(e){`, Else somple click event will work.

Comment: Use a alert statement inside the event. So that you can got to know. And plase clear the cache once. Most of the time we face the on this in al most all browser.

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because you haven't disabled the default behavior of the anchor element. on the click event stop the default behavior with `event.preventDefault()`

something like this

```
$( "#tab-personal" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); # this will prevent the default behavior
    # do something
});
```

as it is already inside `ready()` function you need not wrap it in  one more ready function

Comment: are you using jquery tabs?

Comment: No, custom tabs with HTML and CSS.